# Applying animation for a ProgressBar on activity load

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have a `ProgressBar` element in my fragment. It is not used to indicate any ongoing completion/load progress, but as a visual indication on how much of some progress is completed as of now. e.g; step 5 of 8.

I want to animate this `ProgressBar` when we this page is loaded, may be from 0 to 5 to give a lively effect. So when the fragment comes into view, the progress bar value is animated in rather than just appearing at the current value. I think fadeIn won't look good.

All I could find from searching is to custom progress animation. Has anyone worked on such a feature, if so your inputs would be very much valuable.

Note that my android:minSdkVersion is API Level 8 (Froyo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Jake Whartons animation libary [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) for this. So you can use Honeycombs ObjectAnimator down to API level 1. To make the animation smooth I would set the max range of the progress bar to ten- or hundredfold of the steps you want to display.

```
mProgressBar.setMax(800); //8 Steps * 100
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgressBar,"Progress",1*100,5*100); //this example animates the transition from step 1 to 5
animator.setDuration(500);
animator.start();
```